# Does ignite auto-generates sql tables in cache?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, ignite

I am new to ignite, I created a basic spring boot application. I ran ignite in terminal as server node and configured client node in my spring boot application. I created an entity and cache. while using sqlline tool in terminal I can't find my sql table in cache. Does ignite autogenerates sql table in cache with field as specified in pojo class?

Employee.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2974414641088735500L;

    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    public Long id;

    @QuerySqlField
    public String username;

    @QuerySqlField
    public String firstName;

    @QuerySqlField
    public String lastName;

    @QuerySqlField
    public String department;

    public String test;
}
```

Ignite Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ApacheIgniteConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Ignite igniteInstance() {
        IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();
        igniteConfiguration.setIgniteInstanceName("igniteTest");
        igniteConfiguration.setLocalHost("127.0.0.1");
        igniteConfiguration.setClientMode(true);

        CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration();
        cacheConfiguration.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
        cacheConfiguration.setName("employee");
        cacheConfiguration.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
        cacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes(Long.class,Employee.class);

        CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration1 = new CacheConfiguration();
        cacheConfiguration1.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
        cacheConfiguration1.setName("itemCache");
        cacheConfiguration1.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
        cacheConfiguration1.setIndexedTypes(String.class,Item.class);

        igniteConfiguration.setCacheConfiguration(cacheConfiguration1);

        return Ignition.start(igniteConfiguration);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your server configuration?. This one is for a client.

Comment: @VladimirPligin I m using the default server config which is present in {ignite-home}/examples/config/ignite-example.xml

Answer (score 0):

`setIndexedTypes` mean that table will be created. Try `!tables` command in `sqlline`. In your case tables are probably named `"employee".EMPLOYEE` and `"itemCache".ITEM`.

Comment: Tables are being created by I am unable to execute sql query using sqlline. I can query tables using @query annotation in spring boot.

Comment: Try running `!tables` in sqlline. Do you see anything?

Comment: I can see the table but I can't query it. Its showing no table with "table_name" exists.

Comment: You need to specify schema for this table, such as `SELECT * FROM "employee".EMPLOYEE LIMIT 1`